# A question about surjectivity proof using a limit, and it's generalisation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

So let's say we have a function $x^3+x^2+2$, this function is surjective, because: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}x^3+x^2+2=\pm \infty$, because of the intermediate value theorem.

If we take a function $x^2+2$, which is not surjective, but if we do the following limit on this function we get only $+\infty$.

So my question is, can we generalise surjective function to say:
Every function that has it's limit $\pm \infty$ is surjective. Otherwise it is not.

If the upper statement doesn't hold, what are some functions for which it wouldn't hold, so what are some counter-examples to my example above.

Comment: Well, every **continuous** functions that...

Comment: For continuous functions, yes. Otherwise take $f(x)=x^2/(x-1)$ for example.

Comment: @DonAntonio So my statement is correct ***for every*** function that is continuous.